# Session management in ASP.NET with SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, session, session-state

I am getting the following error while executing `InstallSqlSate.sql` file

> Msg 14261, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_add_category, Line 32
>   The specified @name ('[Uncategorized (Local)]') already exists.
>
> SQLServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot be notified of
>   this action.

I want details about what is that error and how to fix it?

Comment: Run `aspnet_regsql.exe` from the command line.  You'll find it in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`

Answer (score 0):

InstallState.sql is not intended to be run directly. Use aspnet_regsql.exe instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in SQL2000. Might work for 2005.

> If you receive this error message, first make sure that the SQL Server
>   Agent service is running. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type **Services.msc**, and then
>      click **OK**.
> 2. In the **Services** window, locate the SQL Server Agent
>      service.
> 3. Make sure that the value of the **Status** column of the SQL
>      Server Agent service is **Running**.
>
> If the SQL Server Agent service is running, this problem occurs
>   because the SQL Server Agent service cannot interpret the dot mark (.)
>   that represents the local computer in the ObjectName registry entry
>   under the following registry subkey. For a default instance, the
>   registry subkey is as follows:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLSERVER\ For
>   a named instance, the registry subkey is as follows:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQL$InstanceName\
>   Note InstanceName is a placeholder for the instance of SQL Server.

Mine was not running, it was "disabled". If this is the case for you: Right click properties, change it from disabled to Automatic. Press OK. Then right click the SQL Server Agent service and click "Start". It should change to have the "Running" status.

from: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/911841